# R how to select the database I connect?

Tags: mysql, r, mariadb

I have both MySQL and MariaDB on my computer, originally I only used MySQL, but recently I have a program using MariaDB. so I used the following script to extract the data

```
library(RMariaDB)

# export table from mySQL 
database <- "movesdb20201105"
mydb = DBI::dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user='moves', password='moves', #actually from RMySQL
                      dbname = database, host= "localhost")

rs_tmp = DBI::dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT * FROM emissionratebyage")
```

but I look into the connection, it connects to MySQL not MraiaDB, how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I finally added port and solved the problem, MySQL 3306 Maria 3307

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is the successor of MySQL. Maybe just a wrong label?
Also try unloading the MySQL library.